# search for inner element, using Xpath or LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, xpath, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have XML like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Hospital>
  <DR>
    <Salary>1000</Salary>
    <bonus> 3 </bonus>
  </DR>
  <Nurse>
    <Shift> </Shift>
  </Nurse>
</Hospital>
```

I want to search in Dr node for sub element for example  if not exist insert it and update the file,

also how to update the XML version , using C#

Answer (score 0):

As for updating the XML version, so far Microsoft's XML parsers and APIs solely support XML version 1.0, there is no support for XML version 1.1.

As for checking whether the `DR` element has no `foo` child element and adding one you can do e.g.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
XElement dr = doc.Root.Element("DR");
if (dr.Element("foo") == null)
{
  dr.Add(new XElement("foo", "..."));
}
doc.Save("output.xml"); // of course here you can overwrite the original file if needed
```

Comment: how to add attribute to foo sub element